# systemctl: unrecognized option '--value'

Tags: centos, systemd, command, services, systemctl

I am using the systemctl command to fetch only the value of a property. And executing the below command:

```
systemctl show -p ActiveState --value servicename
```

I'm getting this error:

```
systemctl: unrecognized option '--value'
```

My system is CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core) and `systemctl --version` is systemd 219

Answer (score 4):

The `--value` option was [added in systemd 230](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/v230/NEWS#L126) so you can't use it with systemd 219 and you'll need to parse the value yourself with for example something like

```
# systemctl show -p ActiveState firewalld | cut -d"=" -f2
active
```

Comment: Thank you Vojtech.

Comment: Note that the link "added in systemd 230" points to a line that will change over time since it's the most recent version. Now in fact the anchor is wrong. I think we need to identify the exact commit and point to that permalink

Comment: Good point, I changed the link to point to the v230 tag version of the NEWS file.